# Javascript calculator unanswered questions

Tags: javascript, calculator

Thanks for your help everyone! Aside from the math I have a couple more questions.

1) When a field isn't filled out, I wanted it to throw an alert and to focus back on the top-most entry field that hasn't been filled out. Ex) Apr was filled out, but not the loan term, so the focus should go back to the loan term text box.

2) I don't want the monthly payment to display until all of the text fields are filled out.

I've tried to play around with it, but it's still not working :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <!-- This is assign05.html -->
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> JavaScriptcript Mortgage Calculator </title>
<script>

    //Display the total sum
    function display(x, y, z) {
          var num = x + y + z;
    var n = num.toString();
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your monthly payment is " + n;
    }

    // Validate the form
    function validateForm(x, y, z) {
        var x = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["apr"].value);
        var y = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["loanTerm"].value);
    var z = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["loanAmount"].value);

    // If statements
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("APR must be filled out");
        document.getElementById("apr").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (y==null || y=="") {
        alert("Loan Term must be filled out");
        document.getElementById("loanTerm").focus()
        return false;
    }
    else if (z==null || z=="") {
        alert("Loan Amount must be filled out");
        document.getElementById("loanAmount").focus()
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Display
        display(x, y, z);
    }
    return false;
    }

    //Reset the form (this isn't working)
    function resetForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad=document.getElementById("apr").focus();>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;" method="post">
    APR: <input type="number" id="apr" value=""><br/>
    Loan Term: <input type="number" id="loanTerm" value=""><br/>
 Loan Amount: <input type="number" id="loanAmount" value=""><br/>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate Payment Button</button>
    <input type="button" onclick="resetForm()" value="Reset form">
</form>
<div id="total"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you `parseInt("")` an empty string it returns `NaN`, I'm guessing that's your problem. Edit: so you should just need to add `|| x == "NaN"`

Comment: So like this? if (x==null || x=="" || x=="NaN")

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Is it maybe because I am passing parameters in validate form when I don't need to? I just don't know

Comment: I'm not certain what the issue is, if you can create a jsfiddle I can help you more.

Comment: Uh, im sorry I don't know how to do that. My entire code is up above though.

Comment: Woops, I forgot that `NaN` isn't actually a string. This will definitely work: `if(x==null || x=="" || x.toString()=="NaN")`

Comment: Oh it works! Genius! Thank you. For some reason it pops up with 2 alerts (when I close one, another is behind it(it didn't use to do that)) Maybe its an internet explorer thing :/

Comment: Also, remember that `parseInt` takes 2 parameters - the 2nd is radix. Since your calculations are based on decimal system, you should be using `parseInt(x, 10)` to get the correct value in all browsers (some of older versions use radix of 8 as default). See more here: [parseInt() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `parseInt()` on an empty string (which is what you get when getting the .value of an empty text field) it will return `NaN`. Simple solution is to just add an additional check.

```
if(x==null || x=="" || x.toString()=="NaN"){}
```

Comment: If I wanted to change the integers to whole numbers, do I just do parseFloat()?

Comment: You could also use the isNaN(x) function built into JavaScript. This would avoid having to cast the response to a string.
if(x==null || isNaN(x)){}

Comment: Excellent point, not sure how I wasn't aware of that function.